# Edit/delete/list in one page

Tags: php, mysql, database, edit

I am trying to make a page with all the information from a database, where a user would be able to edit or delete rows. I don't quite understand how to make the buttons work. I am a beginner in programming, would be really grateful if you could help me.

My code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$sqlquery="SELECT artistId, firstname, lastname, nationality, dateofBirth, otherInfo, image  from $artists order by 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlquery);
if($result)
{
echo "<table id=\"artists\">";

                while  ($sqlRow=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
                {


                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo"<input type=\"text\" name=\"textid[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['artistId']."\"/>"; 
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textfirstname[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['firstname']."\"/>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textlastname[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['lastname']."\"/>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textnation[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['nationality']."\"/>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textdateofbirth[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['dateofBirth']."\"/>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textotherinfo[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['otherInfo']."\"/>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textimage[]\" value=\"".$sqlRow['image']."\"/>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"return confirm('Edit the record?')\" name=\"edit[]\" value=\"Edit\" />";
                    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete[]\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"return confirm('Delete the record?')\"/>";
                    echo "<input type=\"reset\" name=\"reset[]\" value=\"Cancel\" />";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }


}
print '</table>';

if($_POST)
{
$artistId=$_POST['textid'];
$fname=$_POST['textfirstname'];
$lname=$_POST['textlastname'];
$nation=$_POST['textnation'];
$dateofBirth=$_POST['textdateofbirth'];
$otherInfo=$_POST['textotherinfo'];
$image=$_POST['textimage'];


for($i=0;$i<sizeof($artistId);$i++)
{
if (isset($_POST['edit[$i]']))
{
$query="UPDATE $artists set artistId='".$artistId[$i]."', firstname='".$fname[$i]."', lastname='".$lname[$i]."', nationality='".$nation[$i]."', dateofBirth='".$dateofBirth[$i]."', otherInfo='".$otherInfo[$i]."', image='".$image[$i]."' WHERE (artistId='".$sqlRow['artistId']."')";
}

}
}
?>
```

Comment: where is form close tag?

Comment: so for delete maybe use something like `<form action=# method=post><input hidden=$artistId><input type=submit name=delete></form>` also make sure you dont place a form inside a form. the close form tag will break the form up.

Comment: @kumar_v I have it now, but doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a formular around the input fields.

For example:

```
<form name="form" action="yourfilename.php" method="post">
    <input....
</form>
```

Comment: I made it but it didn't change anything :( I guess that I have a mistake in the loop but I cannot figure it out

Comment: yes, the update, the records stay the same. I haven't done the delete yet

Comment: Well what are you doing with $query? There is no mysqli_query() or mysqli_prepare() and mysqli_execute()

Comment: Well just try to add after $query = ... the line mysqli_query($connect, $query);

Comment: Then try to echo after $query something and look, if it's printed out, so that the loop is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the update query at the end. Execute it to the see the changes.
If everything else is right then it should work as per your requirement.

```
if (isset($_POST['edit[$i]']))
{
$query="UPDATE $artists set artistId='".$artistId[$i]."', firstname='".$fname[$i]."', lastname='".$lname[$i]."', nationality='".$nation[$i]."', dateofBirth='".$dateofBirth[$i]."', otherInfo='".$otherInfo[$i]."', image='".$image[$i]."' WHERE (artistId='".$sqlRow['artistId']."')";
mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: I did it, but no result :( also I changed the mysql_* to mysqli_*

Comment: i think it is not going in the if loop. Change your condition to if(isset($_POST[edit[$i]])).

Answer (score 0):

```
$namearray("textFirstName", "textLastName"); //use capital naming convention
$sqlarray("firstName", "lastName"); //only using 2 fields for demo purposes here
$n=0;
while($sqlRow=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){    
echo "<form action=# method=post><input hidden=$artistId><input type=submit name=delete></form>";
  echo "<form>";

  echo "<input type=text name='" . $namearray[$n] . "[]' value='" . $sqlarray[$n] . "'>";
  echo "</form>";
}

if($_POST['delete']){
  //run delete sql here
  //$query = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE clause=clause';
}

if($_POST['update']){
  //run edit sql here
  //$query = 'UPDATE table SET col=value';
}

if(isset($query)) mysql_query($query);

//please note  that mysql is deprecated and that mysqli should be in use
```